# How to make two lists out of three on Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

The goal is: turn 3 lists of the same length into 2 lists, the length of which does not differ by more than 1, elements from different source lists must alternate and their order must not be violated. For example: if ‘A’ went before ' B’ in the source list, then ‘B’ cannot go before ‘A’ in the final list.
So, I decided to wrote a function:

```
def list_3_2(list1,list2,list3):
    #split all lists in one list
    a=sum((list(i) for i in zip(list1,list2,list3)),[])
    #I want to separate list "a" to two new lists: l1 and l2 
    l1=[]
    l2=[]
    #//////
    return(l1,l2)

list_3_2(['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9'])
```

Then I faced the problem of separation. I found some similar issues, but their lists were structured differently, like `main_list=['3 5', '1 2', '1 7']`. I get the another result, after the unification: `a=['1', '4', '7', '2', '5', '8', '3', '6', '9']`. How could i separate this list?

Comment: By *"elements from different source lists must alternate"* you mean that in the resulting lists, for any pair of consecutive elements it is true that they are from different source lists? Does the implication also hold in the opposite direction (that is, is my paraphrase equivalent to yours?) Also, is it true that in the union of all original lists, no two elements are equal?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan   So, answering to your first question: Yes, i mean  in the resulting lists, for any pair of consecutive elements it is true that they are from different source lists. I don't understand your second question. And the third question: It's not true.

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: @Ben I was wondering if my paraphrase was truly equivalent to your proposition (in italics in my original comment), or if only whenever your proposition was true, my paraphrase was true, not the other way around. I suspect they are equivalent. Also, if you claim that the answer to my third question is not true, then it is possible for the problem to have no solution, correct? (If all elements in the original arrays are equal for example).

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Sorry, i made a mistake while answering to your third question. Answer to your third question is true. And I'm agree that your paraphrase and proposition are  equivalent

Comment: @Ben Fantastic, I'll compose a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to the finalizing information you shared, I believe you were extremely close to the solution, you just needed to split the final array. What do you think about this?

```
def list_3_2(list1,list2,list3):
    a=sum((list(i) for i in zip(list1,list2,list3)),[])
    return a[:len(a)//2], a[len(a)//2:]
    
print(list_3_2(['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']))
```

Basically, splitting the list into two parts, where one is at most `1` element larger than the other, corresponds to splitting an arbitrary list at the index of the rounded-down midpoint. The parts will be of different length iff the original array (chain of inputs) has odd length.

The midpoint index of an array is `len(array)//2` - `len(array)` is the full length and `//2`  is the operation of "division in half rounded down".

Lastly, to split the array using this midpoint index, we use the `splicing` mechanism in python. The syntax is as follows:

`a[:m]` = all elements of `a` from index `0` (= the beginning) to index `m-1`.

`a[m:]` = all elements of `a` from index `m` to index `len(a) - 1` (= the end).

Comment: This amazing! Thank you! Could you comment this line of your code `return a[:len(a)//2], a[len(a)//2:]` with more details, please

Comment: @Ben I added additional info to my answer body :)

Comment: Thank you for information! It was really useful!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

```
from itertools import chain


def list_3_2(l1, l2, l3):
    x = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(l1, l2, l3)))
    m = len(x) // 2
    return (x[:m], x[m:])
```

Zip the lists, concatenate the resulting tuples into a single list, then split that in half.

Comment: This is equivalent to my solution, upvoting.

Comment: Here the result, after running your code:NameError: name 'chain' is not defined

Comment: Not quite equivalent; using `sum` means you create a bunch of temporary `list` objects on the way to creating the final result. `chain.from_iterable` simply creates a single iterable that can be consumed to create a *single* list. (Similar to the difference between `s = s1 + s2 + s3` and `''.join([s1, s2, s3])`.

Comment: @Ben I forgot the `import` statement that brings `chain` into scope.

Comment: Of course, equivalence, in the context of my comment, means "produces the same output for input".

Answer (score 0):

Hey try that hope is that what you want

```
def list_3_2(list1,list2,list3):
        #split all lists in one list
        #I want to separate list "a" to two new lists: l1 and l2 
        a=[]
        [a.extend(j) for j in (list(list(i) for i in zip(list1,list2,list3)))]
        #//////
        div=int(len(a)/2)
        l1=a[0:div]
        l2=a[div:]
        return  l1,l2
    
print(list_3_2(['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, but your program works not quite correct. Checked it one more time, please

Comment: But expected output look like: **(['1', '4', '7', '2'], ['5', '8', '3', '6', '9'])** . Your output: **[['1', '4', '7'], ['2', '5', '8']]**

Comment: ah okay i will fix it now